# How to Fetch API (POST) using one single URL but with each 4 different parameters

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am still new to JavaScript. As per title, how to fetch a single API URL but with 4 different parameters. My goal is to display 4 different categories as the result.

Example (I have 4 different categories):

```
const category = [1,2,3,4];
```

I want to make each category calls for an API

**Method 1**

To call category 1:

```
const url = 'http://www.myapiurl.com/thisapi';
const parameter = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=1`
    };
fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(object => {})
```

To call category 2:

```
const url = 'http://www.myapiurl.com/thisapi';
const parameter = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=2`
    };
fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(object => {})
```

To call category 3:

```
const url = 'http://www.myapiurl.com/thisapi';
const parameter = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=3`
    };
fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(object => {})
```

To call category 4:

```
const url = 'http://www.myapiurl.com/thisapi';
const parameter = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=4`
    };
fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(object => {})
```

Or maybe I can simplify them a bit like this:

**Method 2**

```
const parameter1 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=1`
    };

const parameter2 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=2`
    };

const parameter3 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=3`
    };

const parameter4 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=4`
    };

    Promise.all([
        fetch(url,parameter1).then(value => value.json()),
        fetch(url,parameter2).then(value => value.json()),
        fetch(url,parameter3).then(value => value.json()),            
        fetch(url,parameter4).then(value => value.json()),            
        ])
        .then((value) => {
           console.log(value)
          //json response
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

But all of these are very redundant and unnecessary repetition. What if I have 50 categories? How do I simplify all of these Fetch API calls? Please give me an enlightenment.

Comment: You could create a function out of your code, and use recursive calls to the function, you need to add code to handle the response, when you get a positive response then call the function again with the new parameter.

Comment: What the API returns is governed by the API so if you have to request each "category" individually there is no way around that. Unless there is an endpoint to fetch ALL DATA and then process it on the the front end.

Comment: @GifCo so do you mean I am indeed have to code each 4 different fetch like my original post?

Comment: @AndrewDaly do you mean I have to make a fetch calls inside forEach or loop function? Are there any example about the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take it a step further. Since your method, headers and part of the body are all identical, just extract that to one function. Custom-build the parameters to the category, then call `fetch`.

```
const thatPostFunction = category => {
  const method = 'POST'
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  const body = `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=${category}`

  return fetch(url, { method, headers, body })
}

const categories = [...category ids...]

const promises = categories.map(c => thatPostFunction(c))

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((value) => {
    console.log(value)
    //json response
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: `categories.map(thatPostFunction)`, cleaner

Comment: Thank you, after a bit of tweak (const promises =) and a tweak of categories ID, I have tried your code and get the each category calls ^_^ Thank you very much, God Bless You

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a function that runs all of them:

```js
const categories = [1,2,3,4];

const postUrls = (items) => {
  const promises = []

  items.forEach(item => {
    const url = 'http://www.myapiurl.com/thisapi';
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=${item}`
    };
    const prms = fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    
    promises.push(prms)
  })
  
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

postUrls(categories)
.then(data => console.log('Done!'))
```

Comment: You can also build the Promises array using `promises = items.map( item => { ... ; return prms;})`

Comment: @Hybrid Thank you very much for stopping by and teach me ^_^ God Bless You

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function to convert a category id to a Promise, and then write a wrapper function to convert an array of category ids to a Promise resolving to an array of fetch results:

```js
const fetchCategory = (catId) => {
  const url = 'http://www.myapiurl.com/thisapi';
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=${catId}`
  };
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
}

const fetchCategories = (categories) => Promise.all(categories.map(fetchCategory))

const categories = [1, 2, 3, 4]

fetchCategories(categories).then(categoryResults => {
  // here categoryResults is an array of the fetch results for each category.
  console.log(categoryResults)
})
```

```html
<script>
    // Faking out fetch for testing
    const fetch = (url, opts) => Promise.resolve({
      json: () => ({
        categoryId: `${opts.body.slice(opts.body.lastIndexOf('=') + 1)}`, 
        more: 'here'
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for stopping by and teach me ^_^ God Bless You

Answer (score 0):

If your API is flexible then you may be able to ask for all 4 categories at the same time. I have seen APIs do it like this:

```
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=1,2,3,4`
```

And I have seen them do it like this:

```
        body: `USERID=userid&TOKEN=usertoken&CATEGORY=1&CATEGORY=2&CATEGORY=3&CATEGORY=4`
```

Again, your API would need to be able to enumerate through the categories and return the results in some kind of object or array.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API url isn't flexible, but the parameter is. The API url stays the same www.theurlapi.com only the body parameters are changing, eg: category 1, 2, 4. But I have tried using @Joseph code and it works perfectly and achieve what I wants